# Disable "Share" tab in MS Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

### My problem

MS word 2016 adds a "Share" button above the ribbon.  It is bound to the "Y" Alt-access key, which conflicts with another extension I have installed.

[image: Share tab in task bar]

This adds extra key presses to a keyboard shortcut I use frequently, and means I need to retrain my muscle memory and use a different series of keystrokes on workstations with different Word installations. As I don't use the "Share" functionality, I'd like to remove this button.

### What I've tried

- I can't find an option within Word.
- I've added the Registry DWORD key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\SignIn\SignInOptions` with a value of  `1`
- Per [Microsoft's advice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/remove-share-button-from-upper-right-hand-corner/c74d156f-0f8a-4e2a-b039-950026867ab3), I've downloaded a [Group Policy Template](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030), but when I run the program it doesn't seem to create any files; when I run "Edit group policy" from the Control Panel, Word isn't listed under User Configuration→Administrative templates, and I can't find a profile to add.
- Setting the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\Word\DisabledCmdBarItemsList\TCID1` to `26594` (per @harrymc below) disables the button but doesn't remove the Alt shortcut:

> [image: Disabled but still associated with Y1]

Comment: Just do not use the button. There are many buttons in Word. I do not recommend registry changes to try to fix this as registry changes often go bad.

Comment: The button collides with an `Alt-Y` shortcut, adding extra key presses to a keyboard shortcut I use frequently, and meaning I need to use a different series of keystrokes when using a Word 2016 machine.

Comment: Most of the Office products in the suite use the Share button. So all the apps use the same button. Most App Vendors provide for different Hot Keys so as not to collide with Microsoft.  Check that.

Comment: I strongly recommend avoiding Alt+ shortcuts because of this. These shortcuts may change over time, as well. Instead, use Shift+Alt+ or something else. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330 You have lots of other keyboard shortcuts available.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the Share button in Office 2016/2019 :

- Open the registry editor `regedit`
- Ensure that the following keys exist (create missing keys):

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\DisabledCmdBarItemsList
  ```
- Add a String value named TCID1 (if already exists, increase the number)
- Set its value to `26594`
- Start Word and check that the button is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – this disables the share button but does not remove it, including from the ALT sequence

Comment: I don't think that an option exists to *remove* it. If the Alt key is still enabled, then this is a bug by Microsoft. You could signal it in the Feedback Hub.

Comment: Yes, I agree with harrymc, we can grey out the Share button, but we can not remove it.

Comment: Thanks – I've filed a Feedback Hub report: https://aka.ms/AAgs0yx